# Add Voice Search in PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I want voice search instead of always typing in the PlaceAutocompleteFragment so that user has the extra feature.
By following the tutorial on Google's website https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete, I able to get the the places auto complete to run fine but this voice search feature is not covered in google's tutorial.

Is there any easy way by which I can add that mic icon right corner of the search box and hence provide the voice search feature to user.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not such feature introduced by now. Alternatively you can use Google MIC to recognize voice and show it in any TEXTVIEW. Geocode it to get lat lng from the address and show it on your Map.

Comment: Please be more elaborative.